# How to change the URL of sub menu page?

Tags: wp-admin, user-meta, sub-menu

I'm trying to add a sub page under users in admin panel and everything works fine but I have a little problem when clicking on the created page the url changes and refer to my page as query string not new php file

URL : **http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/users.php?page=filtered.php**

and I want : **http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/filtered.php**

is there any way to do so ?

```php
function wporg_options_page(){

    add_submenu_page( 
        'users.php',
        'Filtered Users', 
        'Filtered Users', 
        'manage_options', 
        'filtered.php', 
        'filtered_user_page_html', 
        1 );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'wporg_options_page');
```

Comment: You can’t have a URL like that. The admin does not rewrite URLs, so the only way to have that would be to add a filtered.php to the wp-admin directory, which you must not do. You will need to use the normal admin URL format for settings pages.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie

Comment: If this is a working page on your site:

`http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/users.php?page=filtered.php`

And you want that to be accessed with this URL:

http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/filtered.php
 you could do that with rewrite rules. I'm not sure if that's what you want though as perhaps you're trying to have the menu item URL generated differently?

Comment: @mozboz, Yes I want to do so , but I don't know how to use rewrite rules

Answer (score 0):

As per the requirement in the comments, one way to do that rewrite is with .htaccess. This may be possible with Wordpress rewrite functions too, but I find .htaccess easier as there are some constraints with the Wordpress functions.

If your Wordpress installation is at `http://localhost/wordpress` then your .htaccess should be in the `wordpress` directory.

Add this to the top of it to do the rewrite you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/filtered.php(/.*)$ wp-admin/users.php?page=filtered.php$1 [NC,L]
```

Note:

- This must be added in your root `.htacess` file **above** the start of the Wordpress Rules
- This will not change the URL in the browser. You can add a redirect if you want it to redirect with e.g. `[R=301,NC,L]`
- This is untested but should do what you want or get you close to what you need.
- As per the comments this is only the URL that you can use to access this page, this won't automatically change any URL's that get rendered in Wordpress